# When do I need Awareness?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

Paladins and classes that can cross-class Paladin abilities have access to a skill called [Awareness](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Awareness):

> Nullifies chance of suffering critical damage.
>   Duration: 15s
>
> 120 second cooldown.

But I don't seem to notice a lot of critical strikes to begin with. When should I be using this ability?  And is it worth it for my Dark Knight and Warrior to cross-class it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awareness has limited usefulness on PLD right now. Tank busters generally can't crit, so you can't use it preemptively, and the damage mitigation from nullifying critical auto-attacks is minimal. That said, there's no real reason *not* to use it anyway if you can remember it's there.

I wouldn't recommend assigning it as one of your cross-class abilities on DRK. You're better off taking Mercy Stroke to squeeze out a bit more DPS (just don't rely on getting the heal from it).

So, it's not very useful on PLD, and not even worth the ability slot on DRK, but it turns out to be incredibly useful on WAR once you get Raw Intuition at level 56. Raw Intuition parries all attacks from the *front* for 20s, but all attacks from the *flank* or *rear* during that time will crit. Pairing Raw Inituition with Awareness can remove the rear/flank critical hit penalty on Raw Intuition for 15s. It's probably not going to matter much on bosses, but this can be a really effective mitigation strategy on trash.

Comment: Just tested real quick, and "nullify" is wrong. Raw Intuition + Awareness will parry all attacks from the front, while flank and rear attacks just do normal damage. So it essentially becomes a 20% damage reduction for frontal attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Awareness is great for keeping damage consistent during a stressful phase. It's not great if you get crit by an auto attack for that slightly bit more damage than I'm expecting as a healer.

"More Crits" is also sometimes a gimmick for a battle. In Shiva EX for example, her bow phase is full of crits and high damage, and Awareness makes that a lot easier.